# Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, indexing

I'm trying to fetch paginated data from a mongodb database (using mongoose) while applying some filtering, but i have the following error:

```
Exec error resulting in state FAILURE :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.'
```

Here is the request:

```
    const users = await User.find(
      {role,field,level, state},
      '_id firstname lastname field role level state updatedAt',
      {
        collation: { locale: 'fr' },
        limit,
        skip,
        sort: {
          [sortBy]: sortBy === 'updatedAt' ? -1 : 1,
        },
      }
    );
});
```

To fix this issue I tried to add an index as follows:

```
userSchema.index(
  {
    role: 1,
    field: 1,
    level: 1,
    state: 1,
    updateAt: 1,
  },
  { background: true }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
User.createIndexes();
```

But I'm still getting the same error
I know a possible fix is to increase the ram memory but I prefered not to do so

Here is the output of `db.users.getIndexes()`

```
...
{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
     "role" : 1,
     "field" : 1,
     "level" : 1,
     "state" : 1,
     "updateAt" : 1
   },
   "name" : "role_1_field_1_level_1_state_1_updateAt_1",
   "ns" : "esgcvak-v1.users",
   "background" : true
}
```

Here is the output of `Query.prototype.explain()` method of mongoose (I can see `indexFilterSet: false`)

```
[
  {
    queryPlanner: {
      plannerVersion: 1,
      namespace: 'esgcvak-v1.users',
      indexFilterSet: false,
      parsedQuery: [Object],
      collation: [Object],
      winningPlan: [Object],
      rejectedPlans: []
    },
    executionStats: {
      executionSuccess: false,
      errorMessage: 'Exec error resulting in state FAILURE :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.',
      errorCode: 96,
      nReturned: 0,
      executionTimeMillis: 9,
      totalKeysExamined: 0,
      totalDocsExamined: 362,
      executionStages: [Object],
      allPlansExecution: []
    },
    serverInfo: {
      host: 'iad2clus12br0vz177',
      port: 53623,
      version: '4.0.10',
      gitVersion: 'c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766'
    },
    ok: 1,
    operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1666107129 },
    '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] }
  }
]
```

Here's my model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    field: {
      type: String,
    },
    firstname: {
      index: true,
      type: String,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
    },
    level: {
      type: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
    },
    state: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    strict: 'throw',
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: an index with a collation cannot support an operation that performs string comparisons on the indexed fields if the operation specifies a different collation , e.g to satisfy your query the index need to be createed with collation: { locale: 'fr' } otherways you will do COLSCAN hitting the 32MB default sort memory limit ...

Comment: Also, `indexFilterSet` is about [usage of index filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/#mongodb-data-explain.queryPlanner.indexFilterSet) which are also known as "plan cache filters". Those are like server side hints, and the fact that the value is `false` is totally normal. The database will still use indexes for the query if it can. In this case, as @R2D2 points out, it [cannot use the index due to the collation mismatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/collation/#collation-and-index-use)

Comment: You may want to check out [allowDiskUse](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/)

Comment: @R2D2 You're right

Comment: Hi , @Baboux  please, materialize your reply above :) accepting my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

an index with a collation cannot support an operation that performs string comparisons on the indexed fields if the operation specifies a different collation , e.g to satisfy your query the index need to be createed with collation: { locale: 'fr' } otherways you will do COLSCAN hitting the 32MB default sort memory limit ...